# Tomcat hangs to 2 min while statup

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, startup

I'm having some very strange behavior in Tomcat 7. While startup Tomcat get a stuck for 2 minutes in **internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator (QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.java:47) - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory**

The server log looks like:

```
2017-04-30 16:51:13,850 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] dialect.Dialect (Dialect.java:157) - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2017-04-30 16:51:14,013 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:379) - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'cg.data.internal'
2017-04-30 16:51:14,038 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] version.VersionManager (VersionManager.java:32) - version initialized: 18.0.0.1I0
2017-04-30 16:51:26,743 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator (QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.java:47) - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-04-30 16:53:30,394 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] framework.CglibAopProxy (CglibAopProxy.java:265) - Unable to proxy method [public final javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getDataSource()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
2017-04-30 16:53:30,395 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] framework.CglibAopProxy (CglibAopProxy.java:265) - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
2017-04-30 16:53:30,395 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] framework.CglibAopProxy (CglibAopProxy.java:265) - Unable to proxy method [protected final java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getConnection() throws org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
2017-04-30 16:53:30,395 INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] framework.CglibAopProxy (CglibAopProxy.java:265) - Unable to proxy method [protected final org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getExceptionTranslator()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
...
```

As you can see the startup stuck between 16:51 to 16:53.
At the end Catalina logs show that application started successfully.
I took java dump at this moment, but it looks like good as well.

Java dump:

```
2017-04-30 16:29:40
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode):

"HSQLDB Timer @2e5e4dd0" #44 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c472800 nid=0x3518 in Object.wait() [0x000000006a40f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue.park(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fba02cb8> (a org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer.nextTask(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fba02cb8> (a org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskQueue)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Hikari housekeeper (pool HikariPool-0)" #43 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c474800 nid=0x2eec waiting on condition [0x0000000069d6e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fbc94da0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Hikari housekeeper (pool CG_Proficiency)" #41 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c471800 nid=0x2b8c waiting on condition [0x000000006166f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fbe515a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" #39 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c473000 nid=0x2f90 waiting on condition [0x00000000653cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000008061b440> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX server connection timeout 37" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c470000 nid=0x2468 in Object.wait() [0x000000005ee1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000008064ab70> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    - locked <0x000000008064ab70> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46f800 nid=0x3650 waiting on condition [0x000000005e93f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(AprEndpoint.java:1141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ajp-apr-8009-Acceptor-0" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46e800 nid=0x277c runnable [0x000000005ecae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ajp-apr-8009-Poller" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46e000 nid=0x3598 in Object.wait() [0x000000005ea9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1756)
    - locked <0x000000008064d310> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-apr-80-AsyncTimeout" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46d000 nid=0x378c waiting on condition [0x000000005e7ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(AprEndpoint.java:1141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-apr-80-Acceptor-0" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46c800 nid=0x1bb8 runnable [0x000000005e67e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-apr-80-Sendfile" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46b800 nid=0x2454 in Object.wait() [0x000000005e47f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000806e46b0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Sendfile)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Sendfile.run(AprEndpoint.java:2264)
    - locked <0x00000000806e46b0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Sendfile)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-apr-80-Poller" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46b000 nid=0x3768 in Object.wait() [0x000000005e2cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1756)
    - locked <0x00000000806e4520> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" #26 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005c46a000 nid=0x3674 waiting on condition [0x000000005df4f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1510)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"GC Daemon" #24 daemon prio=2 os_prio=-2 tid=0x000000005c468800 nid=0x3048 in Object.wait() [0x000000005d8bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000808d1a68> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x00000000808d1a68> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005bcd2800 nid=0x332c waiting on condition [0x000000005de0e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000080681600> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005cb44800 nid=0x3310 waiting on condition [0x000000005d4ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000008061b440> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005bf99800 nid=0x31d4 runnable [0x000000005d3c9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.findDerivativeType(ReferenceType.java:1264)
    - locked <0x00000000fbc117a0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeFactory.createParameterizedType(TypeFactory.java:44)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromType(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:79)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromTypes(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:129)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15GenericSignatureInformationProvider.getGenericParameterTypes(Java15GenericSignatureInformationProvider.java:48)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.getGenericParameterTypes(ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.matches(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:1003)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.lookupResolvedMember(ResolvedType.java:627)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:68)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:317)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:197)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:319)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:129)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.attemptMatch(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:125)
    - locked <0x00000000fbc93450> (a java.util.HashSet)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x0000000082142178> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    - locked <0x00000000822606c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    - locked <0x0000000081122540> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    - locked <0x0000000081122540> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    - locked <0x0000000081122540> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    - locked <0x0000000080789b40> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x0000000080789b40> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/1846791746.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058db4800 nid=0x3464 runnable [0x000000005b63f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000000806819a8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Accept-1099" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058dee000 nid=0x32c8 runnable [0x000000005b51e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x0000000080681e50> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058de4800 nid=0x3494 runnable [0x000000005b26e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x000000008064b170> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #13 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058b14000 nid=0x2cc0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058b2c800 nid=0x3328 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058b1a000 nid=0x36f4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058b12000 nid=0x30f0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058b1d000 nid=0x2e04 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Command Reader" #8 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058b07000 nid=0x3440 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" #7 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058b01800 nid=0x31b8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" #6 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000058afc800 nid=0x2b00 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058aec800 nid=0x2ee4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000058aeb000 nid=0xd38 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000057b48000 nid=0x5c4 in Object.wait() [0x000000005a09f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000080553528> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000057b41000 nid=0x3724 in Object.wait() [0x0000000059eaf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000000805507c8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021bd800 nid=0x35b4 runnable [0x000000000248e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000000807a60c8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:781)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:727)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
```

Why this happens? May it be some issue related to connection pool configuration?
I use Tomcat 7.0.69, Spring 4, Hibernate 4.